# Enable source map for dart

Tags: dart, source-maps

I want to know how to enable source map for dart in Chrome, (in order to debug a polymer dart project).

I've checked the "Enable JS source maps" option in DevTools, and added the `//# sourceMapping...` special comment to the end of the compiled script, all files referenced in .js.map are loaded, but the column and line number in console output is still relative to the js file, other than dart. Any idea?

[image]